# angularjs show to get data from json file inside of service

Tags: jquery, json, angularjs, asynchronous

I have json file

```
[
    {
        "Name": "namesfoo3",
        "param1": "paramoffoo3",
        "param2": "param2offoo3"
    },
    {
        "Name": "namesfoo3",
        "param1": "paramoffoo3",
        "param2": "param2offoo3"
    }
]
```

And i want to get data via service and pass it as controller.
js file:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('filtrController',function($http,$scope,testService)
{                      
     Init();
     function Init()
     {
           $scope.data={};
           console.log(testService.getData());    
     }

});

myApp.service('testService',function($http)
{    
     this.getData = function()
     {
         var obj = {content:null};
         $http.get('data.json')
              .success(function(response) {
              // alert();
              console.log(response);
              obj.content = response;
         });
              return obj;      
     }
});
```

But in console log in controller i have return: Object {content: null}.
Data are load correctly, because in service i get correct object and data. So how can i pass data to controller? 
Also is that example still works when i return data from array php, and than pass it as json_encode ?

Answer (score 3):

You can not do a return inside the callback, it is asynchronous and at the time that the response from the server comes, the function have already finished and you will have lost the flow.

What you need to do instead is make use of the promises. So from the service, you return the promise to the controller and when the response comes, the callback will be fired in the controller. Like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('filtrController', function ($scope, testService) {

    Init();

    function Init() {
        $scope.data = {};
        testService.getData().then(data) {
            console.log(data)
        });
    }

});

myApp.service('testService', function ($http) {

    this.getData = function () {
        return $http.get('data.json');
    }
});
```

You can also chain promises, in case that you want to do something with the data in the service. More about it in the [docs about $q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q).

Comment: That's  the best answer here as $http already returns promise, no need for $q for such simple task

Answer (score 1):

You are doing an async call, so you should wait to the callback.

Change your code to:

```
function Init()
{
    $scope.data={};
    testService.getData().then(function(result){
          console.log(result);
    })                  
}
```

Now, in the service you have to wait as well to return the object. Otherwise you are returning  obj before it gets fetched:

```
myApp.service('testService',function($http)
{    
     this.getData = function()
     {
         var defer = $.Deferred();
         $http.get('data.json')
              .success(function(response) {
                  // alert();
                  console.log(response);
                  defer.resolve(response);

              })
              .error(function(error){
                  console.error("The async call has fail");
              });
              return defer.promise();      
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myApp.service('testService',function($http)
{    
     this.getData = function()
     {
         **return** $http.get('data.json')
              .success(function(response) {
              // alert();
              console.log(response);
              obj.content = response;
         });

     }
});
```